# PHP/MySQL: I think I need to use a JOIN here, but I don't know how

Tags: php, mysql, join

This is my query:

```
SELECT messages.id AS m_id, messages.user_id AS m_uid, messages.project_id AS m_pid, messages.date_created AS m_dc, messages.type AS m_type, messages.file_url AS m_fu, messages.message_text AS m_text, messages.deleted AS m_del,
               projects.id AS p_id, projects.name AS p_name, projects.company_id AS p_cid,
               users.id AS u_id, users.name AS u_name
        FROM messages, projects, users
        HAVING `m_pid` = '$project_id' AND m_uid = u_id
        ORDER BY `m_dc` DESC
```

I've been using HAVING instead of WHERE because WHERE doesn't seem to be working with the AS keywords I'm using. The result is that my query is returning more results than I need. I think I'm supposed to be using JOINs here, but I can't really get a grasp on them. Please help!

:) Thanks

Comment: you can use a `WHERE` clause to match let's say `messages.p_id=project.id` there you go an invisible JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true, [you should use JOIN instead of the FROM table1, table2 syntax](http://hashmysql.org/index.php?title=Comma_vs_JOIN).

To answer your issue more directly: the WHERE clause operates on the columns in the tables - the HAVING clause operates on your result set (which includes your aliases).

How do your tables relate to each other?  That is the question you need to answer first - once you have that answer, you put it pretty much directly into the ON clause of the JOIN.

```
SELECT messages.id AS m_id, messages.user_id AS m_uid, messages.project_id AS m_pid, messages.date_created AS m_dc, messages.type AS m_type, messages.file_url AS m_fu, messages.message_text AS m_text, messages.deleted AS m_del, projects.id AS p_id, projects.name AS p_name, projects.company_id AS p_cid,
users.id AS u_id, users.name AS u_name
FROM messages
JOIN users ON messages.user_id = user.id
JOIN projects ON projects.user_id = user.id # this is just a guess
WHERE messages.id = $project_id
ORDER BY `m_dc` DESC
```

To get a better idea of how JOINs relate tables together, you might want to check out this handy [page showing JOINs as Venn diagrams](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
SELECT m.id AS m_id, 
    m.user_id AS m_uid, 
    m.project_id AS m_pid, 
    m.date_created AS m_dc, 
    m.type AS m_type, 
    m.file_url AS m_fu, 
    m.message_text AS m_text, 
    m.deleted AS m_del,               
    p.id AS p_id, 
    p.name AS p_name, 
    p.company_id AS p_cid,               
    u.id AS u_id, 
    u.name AS u_name
FROM messages as m
INNER JOIN projects as p on p.id = m.project_id
INNER JOIN users as u ON u.id = m.user_id              
WHERE m.project_id = '$project_id' 
ORDER BY ....
```

Comment: Ah, thanks so much. Besides not understanding the JOIN situation, I also realized after reading your post, that I'm not supposed to put back-ticks around the field names. That's why I was getting errors in my WHERE clause to begin with.

Comment: @Frank that's not actually true - you should use backticks around database, table, and column names (even aliases).  The errors you were seeing were most likely the result of referring to alias names, instead of actual column names.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
       messages.id AS m_id, messages.user_id AS m_uid, messages.project_id AS m_pid, 
       messages.date_created AS m_dc, messages.type AS m_type, messages.file_url AS m_fu, 
       messages.message_text AS m_text, messages.deleted AS m_del,
       projects.id AS p_id, projects.name AS p_name, projects.company_id AS p_cid,
       users.id AS u_id, users.name AS u_name
FROM 
  messages 
JOIN 
  users ON messages.user_id = users.id
JOIN 
  projects ON projects.id=messages.project_id
WHERE 
  `m_pid` = '$project_id'
ORDER BY 
  `m_dc` DESC
```